# Fragen, deren Antwort man selbst kennt

Tags: discussion

Wie sollte man mit Fragen umgehen, deren Antwort man bereits kennt?
Zum Beispiel bin ich über die Herkunft eines deutschen Sprichwortes gestolpert. Die Antwort fand ich selber sehr interessant und ich denke es könnte auch für andere hier von Interesse sein. Allerdings bin ich hin und hergerissen etwas derartiges zu posten. Schließlich möchte ich mir hier keinen Unfrieden zuziehen.

Pro:

- Unser kleines Forum braucht dringend Fragen, Fragen, Fragen
- Es kann auch eine bessere Antwort als die selbst gefundene dabei herumkommen.

Contra:

- Auf seine eigenen Fragen zu Antworten hat irgendwie etwas von Selbstbeweihräucherung.
- Ich möchte nicht andere in Arbeit stürzen, wenn dieses zur Klärung eigentlich überflüssig ist.
- Ich weiß nicht ob mir noch geholfen wird, wenn ich den Ruf weghabe eh schon alles zu wissen. Auch für mich soll dieses Forum weiterhin einen Nutzen haben.

Sollte Pro für die meisten hier überwiegen: Sollte man seine Absichten bereits in der Frage kenntlichen machen? So könnte man im Vorfeld vielleicht vermeiden, dass sich jemand viel Arbeit macht und anschließend verschnupft reagiert.
Ist so etwas hier überhaupt erwünscht?

Comment: Dein drittes Item ist ein bisschen schräg - In letzter Konsequenz dürftest du dann gar keine Antworten schreiben...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seine eigenen Fragen zu beantworten ist erlaubt und sogar durchaus erwünscht. Man beachte z. B., daß es dafür das „[Self-Learner](https://german.stackexchange.com/badges/14/self-learner)“-Abzeichen gibt.

Natürlich sollte man es nicht auf die Spitze treiben, und sich gegenüber Antworten Anderer stets fair verhalten; das gilt aber sowieso für *alle* Fragen.

Auf der Meta-Meta gibt es einige Diskussionen zum Thema (ich zitiere jeweils die Top-Antwort):

- [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

  > There are already numerous posts that answer their own questions. There's nothing wrong with it. It's even encouraged.
  >
  > It's likely that others have the question for which you have the answer but can't find it anywhere, so post away!
  >
  > — [Sven/CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to/17467#17467)
- [Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)

  > You should answer your own question, and you can get the Self-Learner badge for doing so if the answer has 3 votes.
  >
  > Furthermore, in order to keep your accept rates up, you should consider answering and accepting those tricky questions nobody answered properly.
  >
  > Jeff & Joel have specifically said this is allowed.
  >
  > — [waffles/CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519)
- [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to and answer them myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself)

  > As I mentioned in my answer the best approach is to post your question, wait a day or so and then post your answer.
  >
  > You might get a better answer than you already have and also it's not that obvious that you already knew the answer ;)
  >
  > — [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself/2815#2815)
- [Moving a personal technical blog to Stack Overflow/Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault/2725#2725):

  > > Having this in mind, is it a good practice to post a question and answer it yourself immediately on StackOverflow/ServerFault when you want to share your idea with community?
  >
  > Absolutely, that is one of the design goals for the site: to be a frictionless technical mini-blog where you get reputation for your hard work.
  >
  > Related: [Stack Overflow is You](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/)
  >
  > — [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault/2729#2729)

Comment: Jein. Self-Learner heißt für mich, dass ich zunächst eine Frage hatte und mir das Wissen dazu später aneignen konnte. Wenn ich die Antwort vorher schon weiß, ist das leicht etwas anderes. Danke für deine Antwort, ich denke ich weiß nun wie ich es schreiben sollte.

Comment: Ich habe mir dieselbe Frage wie Markus gestellt. Oft führe ich erste eine kleine Recherche durch, bevor ich eine Frage stelle und komme dann schneller auf eine Antwort als gedacht, denke aber dass die Antwort auch für andere intressant sein könnte. In Zkunft werde ich solche Fragen auch hier stellen.

Comment: @Markus: ist es wirklich relevant _wann_ du dir das Wissen angeeignet hast, solange die Frage interessant und die Antwort hilfreich ist?

Answer (score 4):

Das wird in der [FAQ](https://german.stackexchange.com/faq) beanwortet:

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! – phrase it in the form of a question.

Im Zweifel kann man in der Frage gleich vermerken, dass man die Antwort schon selbst parat hat. Dann können sich die anderen immer noch überlegen, ob sie zusätzlich antworten.

Comment: Ich würde es nicht in der _Frage_ vermerken (da es ja nichts mit der Frage zu tun hat), aber in einem _Kommentar_ wäre es vielleicht gut.

Answer (score 3):

Entweder Frage und Antwort posten oder die Fragestellung im Chat aufbringen.

Nur die Frage zu posten und mit der Antwort zu warten, ohne zu verraten, dass man sie schon kennt, würde mir gar nicht gefallen.

Comment: Das würde mir auch nicht gefallen. Ich werde das in der Frage entsprechend formulieren um klare Verhältnisse zu schaffen. Danke

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nachdem wir die Frage jetzt gesehen haben:

Nein, es ist nicht in Ordnung, das so zu posten. Du *kennst* die Antwort nicht, sondern hast im Internet irgendetwas gefunden. Die genaue suchbare Formulierung und der Link sind entscheidende Informationen für die Frage, um die es geht: Stimmt die gefundene Erklärung oder nicht?

Comment: Welche Frage haben wir jetzt gesehen?

Comment: Auch wenn dem so ist, sollte man das hier eintragen, sofern kein entsprechender Eintrag bereits vorhanden ist. Selbst kann man sich keine Reputation verschaffen, daher ist auch eine vielleicht falsche Antwort der Anreiz für die Gemeinschaft das Thema zu diskutieren und sich die richtige Antwort zu erarbeiten. Dass diese dann auch so kenntlich gemacht wird, ist durch ein entsprechendes Voting gegeben, auch wenn die falsche Antwort noch als akzeptiert markiert ist.